# Cannot Remove DOI and URL from Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

Hope you're safe!

My bibliography still includes URLs and DOIs despite the fact that I've included DOI=false etc in the options for the Biblatex package. How can I remove them?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Rayo2002,
    author = {Rayo, Agust{\'{i}}n},
    doi = {10.1111/1468-0068.00379},
    file = {:Users/James/Documents/St Andrews/Philosophy/MPhil/MPhil Thesis/Readings/Nihilism, Monism, {\&} Pluralism/Word and Objects Rayo.pdf:pdf},
    issn = {0029-4624},
    journal = {No{\^{u}}s},
    month = {sep},
    number = {3},
    pages = {436--464},
    publisher = {Blackwell Publishing Ltd},
    title = {{Word and Objects}},
    url = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1468-0068.00379},
    volume = {36},
    year = {2002}
}

@article{Cartwright1994,
    author = {Cartwright, Richard L.},
    file = {:Users/James/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Cartwright - 1994 - Speaking of Everything.pdf:pdf},
    journal = {No{\^{u}}s},
    number = {1},
    pages = {1--20},
    title = {{Speaking of Everything}},
    url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2215917?seq=1{\&}cid=pdf-reference{\#}references{\_}tab{\_}contents},
    volume = {28},
    year = {1994}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa, doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, date=year, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{chapter}} %gets rid of chapters
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1} %stops capitalisation
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}} %clears issue numbers
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\apanum{#1}} %de-italicises volume numbers

\title{Test Document}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Plural accounts of quantification, such as those endorsed by \citet{Cartwright1994} and \citet{Rayo2002}, allow one to quantify over absolutely everything without commiting oneself to the paradoxical universal set.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of `biblatex-apa` are you using? It should (and does! - at least for me) work in current versions of both `biblatex-apa` (7th. edition) and `biblatex-apa6` (6th. edition). See https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/pull/92.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that `biblatex-apa` implements APA style as closely as possible. As such you can't expect a lot of configuration options that deliberately deviate from APA style.

Comment: Not that it matters for the question, but you (or your `.bib` file program/exporter) should *not* escape special character in the URL field. `url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2215917?seq=1{\&}cid=pdf-reference{\#}references{\_}tab{\_}contents},` is wrong. It would be better to just have `url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2215917?seq=1&cid=pdf-reference#references_tab_contents},`. Though you may want to double check if you need all that, mayb eurl = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2215917},` is enough.

Comment: ... There is also `eprint = {2215917}, eprinttype = {jstor},`

Comment: How do I find out which version of biblatex-apa I am using? I'm unsure what I'm supposed to be looking at in that link! I've been using this version for a while and never had any problems, but all of a sudden it has started adding in the URL and DOI fields...

Comment: The link https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/pull/92 was just a link to show you when the `doi` option (and friends) were added to `biblatex-apa`. You can find out your version by adding `\listfiles` to the very top of your code. LaTeX will then write the package versions to the `.log` file.

Comment: The log file contains two sentences about which version: (i) Package: biblatex 2019/12/01 v3.14 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW); and (ii) File: apa.bbx 2020/02/01 v9.5 APA biblatex references style. Is that useful?

Comment: Yes, you need to update `biblatex-apa`, you need at least v9.6 (2020/02/22). Note that you must have updated `biblatex-apa` not too long ago. Those versions of `biblatex-apa` produce APA style according to the 7th edition of the manual. If you started writing a while ago and/or need APA style from the 6th. edition of the manual, you need to switch to `biblatex-apa6` by replacing `style=apa,` with `style=apa6,`.

Comment: I just realised there was a typo in one of my comments above. Of course I meant "maybe `url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2215917},` is enough".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With version v9.6 (2020/02/22) of `biblatex-apa` or above (the current version is v9.10 from 2020-04-26) the options `doi`, `eprint` and `url` work again and can be used to remove the respective online info. With those versions the MWE works as expected and produces the desired output.

This came after a short period of time where those options were effectively disabled in version v9.0 to v9.5 of `biblatex-apa`. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/pull/92.

Update your system to make sure you have at least `biblatex-apa` v9.6.

---

Note that v9.0 and above of `biblatex-apa` implement APA style from the 7th edition of the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association*.

Versions v1.0 to v7.9 of `biblatex-apa` implemented APA style from the 6th edition of the manual.

**If you want APA style (6th edition) you should use `biblatex-apa6` (`style=apa6`).** This is especially important for people updating from older systems, because `style=apa,` essentially changes APA versions from 6th-ed. APA style to 7th-ed. APA style in November 2019.

---

Not that it matters for the question, but you (or your `.bib` file program/exporter) should not escape special character in the URL field.

```
url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2215917?seq=1{\&}cid=pdf-reference{\#}references{\_}tab{\_}contents},
```

is wrong. It would be better to just have

```
url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2215917?seq=1&cid=pdf-reference#references_tab_contents},
```

Though you may want to double check if you need all that, maybe

```
url = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2215917},
```

is enough. There is also

```
eprint     = {2215917},
eprinttype = {jstor},
```